# I have no idea why my log problem in C keeps giving me 0 or -9223372036854775808 . I think it is the variable type I am using but I'm not sure

Tags: c, cs50

> I am new to C and stack overflow so i'm not really sure where to ask the question. I have to make code for population growth. X is the starting population and Y is the end population. I have to calculate time (T). Every year there are X/3 newborns and X/4 deaths. The formula I am using is log(base: 1+(X/12)/100)(Y/X). To test I use 100 as starting population and 200 as the end population. The years are 8.66 which is rounded up to 9 years. I tried changing the variable type but i'm not sure which type I should use. The code is below. Thanks in advance.<

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


    double log_a_to_base_b( double a, double b)
{
    return log(a) / log(b);
}

int main(void)
{
    
    // Prompt for start size
int X;
  do
  {
     X = get_int ("How many llamas do you start with? \n" );
  }
  while (X < 1);

// Prompt for end size
int Y;
  do
  {
     Y = get_int ("How many llamas do you have after a certain period of time? \n" );
  }
  while (Y < 1 || Y < X);

// Calculate number of years until we reach threshold

     double a = Y/X;
     double b = 1+(X/1200);

{
    printf("Start size : %i \n", X );
    printf("End size : %i \n", Y);
    printf("Years:%f \n", log_a_to_base_b(a, b));

}
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're truncating the result to integer in `return log(a) / log(b);`

Comment: Try to do all the calculations you're doing here by hand on paper. Remember to only allow integers in all individual steps.

Comment: Hi, Im sorry but I have no idea what you are saying. I started with C yesterday so I don't know all the proper terms yet. I did the math on paper and it works.

Comment: Do you know what _integer_ means?

Comment: It's the type of variable I think. Used for numbers without a decimal.

Comment: What do you think `X/1200` will be (without a decimal part) when `X` is `100`? Clue: *With* a decimal part, it is 0.0833333333333.

Comment: So to fix the code I need to use float?

Comment: You can use `float` ... but you're better off with `double`. (More precision and, on modern CPUs, generally no loss of performance.)

Comment: I used float and it prints out inf. Please see the original code above, I changed it to float.

Comment: I just edited it to double and it still prints out inf.

Comment: When you divide an integer with an integer, the result will be an integer. You need to convert at least one of the operands first. You can do with with a cast. Like `double a = X/(double)Y`

Comment: Furthermore, you should learn how to debug your code. For instance, printing the value of `a` right after assignment.

Comment: Sorry but I'm really confused now. What is an operand and a cast? What do you mean with ` double a = X/(double)Y `? What do you mean by debug? Should I print the value of A after assignment or not?

Comment: @Dylan https://github.com/klutt/debug-small-c-programs

Comment: If you don't want to do explicit casts. Do stuff like `double Xd = X; double Yd = Y; double a=Xd/Yd;` and if you want to learn about casting, this could be good https://www.guru99.com/c-type-casting.html

Comment: @klutt Thanks I will look into the debugging process. I don't really know what you mean by double Xd = X; and the rest of the code there. would you please explain really basically because I am really confused now.

Comment: What's unclear about `double Xd = X;`? I'm declaring a variable `Xd` of type `double` and initialize it's value to the value if the `int` variable `X`. That's it.

Comment: Are you taking the CS50 course? Is this an assignment? Doesn't your course material explain this?

Comment: Thank you very much @klutt I have eventually succeeded. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes I am doing a cs50 course but just to learn, not for a certificate and yes it is an assignment. The course material explains part of it, it says that if you receive a wrong answer you are using the wrong variable type. I tried to change the variable type into many things but it still wouldn't work. But now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following,

```
unsigned int log_a_to_base_b( unsigned int a,unsigned int b)
{
    return log(a) / log(b);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%u\n", log_a_to_base_b(10,2)); // Yields 3
     return 0;
}
```

It always returns the correct answer in integer. You will have to change the `%f` in your `printf`. I think that rest of the program runs fine. But you still need to understand that all of the divisions in main are being done on integers. So they will not get you precise results (e.g `3/2=1.000`). And you are also returning `unsigned int`, so that will always give highest integer smaller than the `log`.